# How to remove Serena Dimensions plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, serena

I'm working somewhere that uses Visual Studio 2008 and Dimensions 12.1.

Whenever I start VS I get error messages about the Dimensions SCC plugin not being supported and I must upgrade. It then tells me to restart Visual Studio, which would lead to a nice recursive loop of not getting anythign done.

If I ignore the errors and deselect the Serena plugin in the options (Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection > None) this is ignored next time I start Visual Studio.

Does anyone know how to remove the plugin from Visual Studio?

I prefer to use VS for development and the Dimensions client to perform source control anyway, the switch in tool helps my mind change context.

Comment: Backoffice team did a clean reinstall of Visual Studio which did the job. However it did mean that for an hour mid-afternoon when I had been intending to be using it I couldn't do so. There must be a simpler way to remove the Dimensions plugin than nuking it from orbit.